# How to display a image partially using primefaces/jsf

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, css-sprites

I have a sprite image. I want to displayed just one icon from there. How can that be displayed using jsf/primefaces?

I tried the following code but the complete image is getting displayed.

```
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/image.png" styleClass="lockedImage"/>

.lockedImage{
background-position: -110px -98px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<p:graphicImage>` generates a HTML `<img>` element. You shouldn't be displaying the sprite file as a whole image via `<img>`. You should be using the sprite as **background** image of a block level element such as `<div>`.

E.g.

```html
<div class="lockedImage" />
```

with

```css
.lockedImage {
    width: 16px; /* Set this to icon width. */
    height: 16px; /* Set this to icon height. */
    background-image: url(#{resource['images/image.png']});
    background-position: -110px 98px;
}
```

*(note: `#{resource}` in CSS works only if you're using [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html) to serve the CSS file as JSF resource, otherwise you've to hardcode the right path yourself)*

Note that this problem is completely unrelated to JSF. It's just basic HTML/CSS. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML/CSS code generator. I strongly recommend to take a JSF pause and learn basic HTML/CSS in order to better understand JSF. If necessary, you can generate a `<div>` using `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` in JSF.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion :) I will surely learn basic HTML/CSS. The right understanding of the basics is v important.